# Why I got the error "HTTP method post is not supported by this URL"?

Tags: java, servlets

I am developing a Login app using servlets in eclipse.
I created one login form which contains two text fields(for entering username and password) and one login button. When user click this button it redirects to LoginCheck page where it login details are checked. But problem is that when I run this project I got error : HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL. What is the problem I did''t understand.

Below is my code for `LoginPage`:

```
public class LoginPage extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<form method='post' actin='LoginCheck'>");
            out.println("Username: <input type='text' name='username'>");
            out.println("Password: <input type='password' name='password'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' value='login'>");
        out.println("</form>");
    }
}
```

Now when user click Login button it have to go on the `LoginCheck` page code for this page is as follows:

```
public class LoginCheck extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h3>Checking login details...</h3>");
    }
}
```

and here it gives problem.

This is the XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>LoginApp</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginPage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>LoginPage</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginPage</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginCheck</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>LoginCheck</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginCheck</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginCheck</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Show us your `web.xml`.  How are you even accessing the login page?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just edited my question and added my xml file to it.

Comment: Can you access the `LoginCheck` page correctly via a URL in the browser?  My feeling is that you are redirecting to the wrong URL.

Comment: Opps!!! it not accesssing that URL my URL is **http://localhost:8080/LoginApp/LoginPage**

Comment: You're probably using a relative URL. The XML doesn't help us know how you're accessing the page, the JSP/HTML form defines that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were not actually redirecting to the `LoginCheck` servlet.  Try using `request.getContextPath` instead of what you had.  Here is the full code:

```
public class LoginPage extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        out.println("<form method='post' action='/" + contextPath + "/LoginCheck'>");
        out.println("Username: <input type='text' name='username'>");
        out.println("Password: <input type='password' name='password'>");
        out.println("<input type='submit' value='login'>");
        out.println("</form>");
    }
}
```

Comment: After your edit I getting another error :(  **HTTP Status 404 - /LoginCheck**

Comment: Now when I clicked login button **It does nothing**

Comment: When you hover over the submit button, what URL do you see?

Comment: I get **http://localhost:8080/%3C%=request.getContextPath()%%3E/LoginCheck** This url when I clicked login button (in GOOGLE CHROME)

Comment: Sorry but this will again gives me error :"This webpage is not available" I don't no what to do now !!! :(

Comment: Your comments don't help me very much.  What URL do you get with this latest update?

Comment: Type exactly this into the browser: `localhost:8080/LoginApp/LoginPage` ... what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

If method "get" redirects to "post", your GET request would be transformed into a POST, losing all get data. So my suggestion is, call doPost method from doGet method like...

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><form method='post' action='LoginCheck'>");
        out.println("Username: <input type='text' name='username'>");
        out.println("Password: <input type='password' name='password'>");
        out.println("<input type='submit' value='login'>");
        out.println("</form></html>");
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
      doPost(req, resp);
}
```

Comment: Calling `doPost` from `doGet` (and vice versa) is absolutely not a redirect, and does *not* transform one request type into the other.